# Apostrophe CMS blog module: "That item does not exist."

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've a copy of ApostropheCMS 2 installed on my MacOS but I have a situation with blog module.
When I try to edit existing blog article, I see "That item does not exist.", but I can see it in articles list.

So, here is app.js:

```
'apostrophe-blog': {
  widget: true,
  contextual: true 
},
'apostrophe-blog-pages': {},
'apostrophe-blog-widgets': {},
```

and before 'modules {' I have:

```
 bundles: [ 'apostrophe-blog' ],
```

My apostrophe-blog-page.html contains:

```
 {% block main %}
  <div class="main-content">

        {{ apos.area(data.page, 'body', {
        widgets: {
            'apostrophe-blog': {}
        }
        }) }}

  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Now: the /blog page is empty, in article list I can see all articles, but when I try to edit once, I've the error "That item does not exist."

Any solution?

Comment: Hi Marco, I'm the lead developer of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

This configuration is also present in our "sandbox" project (the one that powers our live demo):

https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe-sandbox

I have tested the scenario you're describing and I cannot reproduce the problem.

What version of the apostrophe and apostrophe-blog modules do you have, exactly? Please check:

`package.json`

In node_modules/apostrophe and node_modules/apostrophe-blog.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @boutell, thank you for your tempestive response. Here my package.json: `{
  "name": "test-project",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Minimal test-project",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "P'unk Avenue",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "apostrophe": "^2.0.0",
    "apostrophe-redirects": "^0.5.7"
  }`

Comment: Here both package versions: **├── apostrophe-blog@2.0.2 extraneous** and **├─┬ apostrophe@2.1.5**

Comment: Hi @boutell, with your sandbox works fine, I'm not understand what's wrong. Well done, thank you so much.

Comment: I can recreate this using a clean install of apostrophe 2 and apostrophe-blog. I haven't been able to isolate the exact issue yet as it is intermittent but what I am seeing happen is that after a certain number of articles being created suddenly this issue will occur. You can reach the article page itself with in context editing but accessing it from the editor will fail with this message. All subsequent articles will suffer from the same issue. The only linking factor is that they will be published but not have a published date. Adding the date to the JSON doc in mongo does not solve it.

Comment: After some further research it looks like what causes this issue is that when the article is created the document generated in the mongo collection aposDocs is missing the publishedAt property and value. If a manually add the publishedDate property and subsequent value it will work as expected in the apostrophe UI.

Answer (score 0):

So I did a fair bit of digging into this issue and it appears to be something related to a previous release of Apostrophe or one of it dependencies (I have been unable to determine exactly where the error is occurring).

Here is the scenario that we have now seen on 3 different Apostrophe deployments that we have running in isolated VM's.

Intermittently, after an undetermined amount of time, the apostrophe-blog module will stop auto creating the publishedAt property in newly create documents in Mongo. For reference if you are digging through your data you can find them in the aposDocs collection using the following query:

List all blog articles

```
db.getCollection('aposDocs').find({"type": "apostrophe-blog"})
```

List all blog articles with missing property

```
db.getCollection('aposDocs').find({"type": "apostrophe-blog", "publishedAt": {$exists : false}})
```

If we then add back in the property with the following statement we can fix the broken articles:

```
db.getCollection('aposDocs').update({"type": "apostrophe-blog", "publishedAt": {$exists : false}}, {$set: {"published": false, "publishedAt": ""}})
```

Your articles should now load. The next step is to keep this from happening again. What we found is that our installation was outdated. You can run the following command to find out if you need to update:

```
npm outdated
```

That will spit out a report like the following:

```
apostrophe         2.1.5  2.10.2  2.10.2  apostrophe
```

In our case apostrophe was outdated pretty substantially. We then updated via:

```
npm update apostrophe
```

This will bring your installation up to date. Testing now we saw that the publishedAt property was properly being auto created for all new apostrophe-blog documents in the DB.